How to partition into batch of records with max batch size limit
I want to batch the students into maximum batch size of 100, partitioned by School. Each teacher can have 12 students. Students of any teacher should not be split into different batches. No. of students in a batch can be less than 100 but not more.
Fiddle URL
With the query used in the fiddle, for the second batch the number students are more than 100 (RowNum 17-32). How can I ensure the students are not split into different batches and there are no more than 100 students in a batch.

Also asked on Stack Overflow.

Your Post here and the duplicate one you made on StackOverflow are lacking important information that makes your question unanswerable to a degree of specificity.
Particularly you say:

From the Output we can see that even though sets of (A, Pam) and (A, Sam) totally contain 8 records they are both assigned Batch Number 2, where as the Batch Number should be 3 for the set (A, Sam).

But that is wrong. 8 divided by 7 = 2 batches. Not 3. One may assume you want at least 1 batch for every TeacherName but in a comment on your duplicate Post on StackOverflow you said you do not. So until you provide more information and better examples on what you're really trying to achieve, the best we can do is tell you that your above premise is incorrect.
That and also this may be a cool problem to dust off the NTILE() function for. You can easily calculate how many batches you need and use that as the integer_expression parameter of it. If you do provide more clear information on your exact end goal, I can update my answer with an example.
From the docs of NTILE():

Distributes the rows in an ordered partition into a specified number of groups. The groups are numbered, starting at one. For each row, NTILE returns the number of the group to which the row belongs.


My apologies, I have added the fiddle link with dataset and query.

NTILE() cannot be used as total number of groups cannot be predefined with a dynamic dataset

@SujaySalins I'll take a look at your update soon. "NTILE() cannot be used as total number of groups cannot be predefined with a dynamic dataset" - Sure but it can be calculated easily, as I mentioned, when the rest of your inputs are constant. E.g. pseudo-code: Total Row Count / Batch Size = Total Number of Groups. Row Count you can get from your dataset on the fly, Batch Size you said is 7 or now 100 in your new update, so then it's just math at that point.

@SujaySalins Ok, I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. At a quick glance it seems like each Teacher in each School has a varying number of Students assigned to them. You want to group Teachers together in the same batch up to 100 total Students (without exceeding 100 in any group) in each School. I understand why you're partitioning by School. I believe we can accomplish what you want. When I get a chance I'll try to update my answer.
